# Как сделать сортировку по цене опции перед экспортом в csv? Opencart модуль CSV Price Pro

Tags: mysql, opencart, csv, group-by

```
    // get Options
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
private function getProductOptions($product_id, $language_id = false) {

    $options = array();

    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(od.name, '|', ovd.name, '|', pov.iuopcod, '|', pov.quantity, '|', pov.price_prefix, '|', TRUNCATE(pov.price, 2), '|', TRUNCATE(pov.base_price, 2), '|', pov.points_prefix, '|', pov.points, '|', pov.weight_prefix, '|', pov.weight, '|', po.required) AS p_options
        FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value` pov
        LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_option` po ON (pov.product_option_id = po.product_option_id)
        LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option_value_description` ovd ON (pov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id AND ovd.language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "')
        LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "option_description` od ON (pov.option_id = od.option_id AND od.language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "')
        WHERE pov.product_id = " . (int)$product_id;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        $options[] = $result['p_options'];
    }

    return implode("\n", $options);
}
```

Comment: Куда нужно дописать ORDER BY pov.base_price ASC?